# Matching array property in elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, json, elasticsearch

I have following documents, in an index called `users`:

```
[ 
 {
   "name": "foo",
   "preferences": [{"id":1, "name":"a"}, {"id": 2, "name":"b"}]
 },
 {
   "name": "bar",
   "preferences": [{"id":2, "name":"a"}, {"id": 3, "name":"c"}, {"id": 4, "name":"d"}]
 }
]
```

and a list of choosen ids, e.g. `var choosenPrefs=[2, 3]`, which match the id property of the preferences.

Now, I want to get all users that have at least one of the ids within their preferences.

I tried different queries, but did not get it...

currently it looks like this:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
          {"prefix": {"name": ""}},
          {
            "terms": {
                "perferences.id": choosenPrefs
            }
          }
        ],
        "filter": {
            "geo_distance": {
                "distance": "10km",
                "location": position
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

I'm using also a distance-filter (which works without the preference-filtering/matching).

The query does not throw any error, but i don't get any results.

I hope someone has an advice?!

PS: I'm using the latest ES version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo (`perferences` instead of `preferences`):

```
   "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
          {"prefix": {"name": ""}},
          {
            "terms": {
                "preferences.id": [2,3]
            }
          }
        ],
        "filter": {
            "geo_distance": {
                "distance": "10km",
                "location": position
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Oh man, how stupid (the downside of schema-less databases... :)) thanks!